# I want to create & print Word forms populated from each row in Excel, but some rows have merged cells

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

A third party provides an Excel spreadsheet containing user information and item selections in rows. Instead of duplicating the user data for each selection, the spreadsheet will merge the user data if the user selects more than one thing (e.g. user wants "beach ball", "tennis racket", and "surfboard", so three rows will have the Name, Address, and Phone info merged).
Example:

```
Name    Address      Phone     Selection
Bill    23 Main st.  555.6767  Beach ball
Sally   12 Front dr. 555.1211  Beach ball
                               Tennis Racket
                               Surfboard
Fred    RD#2 Box 15  555.9876  Surfboard
```

I'm creating a solution for someone else (a non-programmer) to use. They want to print a form with the user's info and their selections (and some other boilerplate text).

I first tried a mail merge from a Word document, but the merge printed a mostly blank form for any merged rows after the first merged row (e.g.Sally's second and third selections). This would work if there were no merged cells. I can manipulate the Excel spreadsheet and remove the merged cells (by duplicating the data with a "copy down"), but that results in one form per selection, and a single user getting multiple forms. This is the work-around solution if I can't find a better way to do it.

My current attempt is to use VBA in the Word document to pull in the Excel data, then determine if a "row" is merged or not, and code for the merged situation. I have that working to some extent:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

    'First, get the user to select the file containing the data
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    fDialog.Filters.Add "Excel Workbooks", "*.xlsx, *.xls, *.xlxm", 1

    Dim blnFileFound As Boolean
    Dim strExtension As String
    Dim blnTest1 As Boolean
    Dim blnTest2 As Boolean
    Dim blnTest3 As Boolean

    Do
        fDialog.Show
        FName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        strExtension = Right(FName, Len(FName) - InStrRev(FName, "."))

        blnTest1 = StrComp(strExtension, "xlsx", vbTextCompare)
        blnTest2 = StrComp(strExtension, "xlsm", vbTextCompare)
        blnTest3 = StrComp(strExtension, "xls", vbTextCompare)
        If blnTest1 = 0 Or blnTest2 = 0 Or blnTest3 = 0 Then
            blnFileFound = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Please locate the Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx, .xlsm, or .xls)", vbCritical, "Incorrect file format"
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop While Not blnFileFound

    'Now open the Excel spreadsheet chosen in the previous section
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FName)

    'If a customer has requested multiple items, the 3rd party's Export to Excel function will merge the customer's info across multiple rows (one for each selection)
    'now loop for each row, create a new page

    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim intCurrentRow As Integer
    Dim intHeaderRow As Integer

    Set sh = objWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    intHeaderRow = 1
    intCurrentRow = 2

    While Not IsEmpty(sh.Cells(intCurrentRow, 1))

        ' create new page with customer's info 
        ' ***** Not sure how to do this ***** 

        ' this next section will determine if there's more than 
        ' one selection for this customer. It will pull the info
        ' for each selection and combine them into one selection field 
        If sh.Cells(intCurrentRow, 1).MergeCells Then
            'combine the selections for the merged rows and put into 
            ' the selection field for this form

            'now determine the next row to read, skipping merged rows
            intCurrentRow = intCurrentRow + sh.Cells(intCurrentRow, 1).MergeArea.Rows.count

        Else
            intCurrentRow = intCurrentRow + 1
        End If
        MsgBox "next row will be " & intCurrentRow

        DoEvents

    Wend

    'release and close object and file handles


End Sub
```

My problem is I'm not sure what to do from here. Am I on the right track? Am I reinventing the wheel and there's already a solution out there?

Some of my pressing questions:
Instead of the merge fields from my first attempt, should I create form fields in my main document for the user data and selections and populate them in code from the Excel data? Is there an example of that anywhere? 
How do I create a new form for each row?

Thanks in advance for any advice and / or links to pages with solutions to similar problems... I haven't found any!

Comment: There are different ways to solve this, even using [mail merge](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-the-rules-for-a-mail-merge-d546ee7e-ab7a-4d6d-b488-41f9e4bd1409). The question is how do you want to proceed? What's the aim here? Then a particular solution can be drafted.

Comment: In your example, the Name column for Sally consists of 3 merged cells?

Comment: If so, then the field should contain the concatenated values from the Selection column.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes to your question about merged cells. My goal is to have one form with the user's info and all of their selections (concatenated; I can do that part simply enough once I've identified the MergeArea, as shown in the code).

Comment: @AAA mail merge (from Word, not using VBA) wasn't optimal. I haven't looked specifically for an example of mail merge using VBA. I'll do so now. 

My goal is to create a Word document that, on document_open(), will open an Excel spreadsheet and print one form per user with all their selections.

My problem is I don't know enough about VBA and its capabilities to know what options I have; a list of possible solutions in general would help me decide which way to go.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, as expecting someone to create a set of 5 or 15 different answers just so you can choose is not likely.

Comment: @JohnG, could you give a rundown of how you'd solve it if it were just one selection per user? Then we'd help amend it

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not asking for people to solve the problem, just confirm I'm heading in the right direction, or point me in the right direction if I'm not heading that way. Some suggestions or search hints would be helpful. 
I can't believe I'm the first person in the history of Word-Excel-mailmerge to come across this problem!

Comment: @AAA As I stated in the OP, I would use a simple mail merge from Word, using the UI to select the Excel spreadsheet as the data source. In fact, I've already done that, but due to the vertically-merged cells, I get a blank form for every row that doesn't contain user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as inferred by @macropod, I decided to concatenate merged rows' item info, then delete the extra rows. 
Since the third-party Excel dump contained blanks for the merged cells that didn't contain an item, I just deleted any row where the first cell was empty.

I then struggled a bit with the mail merge part of the task. It turns out there's a difference between running a VBA merge from Excel and running it from Word. I couldn't find any direct examples of Word using VBA to pull an Excel data source. The documentation for VBA MailMerge is a bit weak on the explanations, and most examples seem to assume I already knew what I was doing, but I figured it out.

My final product is a Word document containing mail merge placeholders where I want the data to go (you can do this in Word in the Mailings tab using a copy of your Excel data), with a VBA code module set to run on document_open. Oh, I dummied up a randomString function for use as a temporary filename; if you're attempting to duplicate my efforts, you'll need to find or write one, or just delete the temp file after each run.

```
Option Explicit
'@Author JPGoetz 20190630

Private Sub Document_Open()

    'First, get the user to select the file containing the Item  data
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    fDialog.Filters.Add "Excel Workbooks", "*.xlsx, *.xls, *.xlxm", 1

    Dim blnFileFound As Boolean
    Dim strExtension As String
    Dim blnTest1 As Boolean
    Dim blnTest2 As Boolean
    Dim blnTest3 As Boolean
    Dim FName As String

    Do
        fDialog.Show
        FName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        strExtension = Right(FName, Len(FName) - InStrRev(FName, "."))

        blnTest1 = StrComp(strExtension, "xlsx", vbTextCompare)
        blnTest2 = StrComp(strExtension, "xlsm", vbTextCompare)
        blnTest3 = StrComp(strExtension, "xls", vbTextCompare)
        If blnTest1 = 0 Or blnTest2 = 0 Or blnTest3 = 0 Then
            blnFileFound = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Please locate the Item  Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx, .xlsm, or .xls)", vbCritical, "Incorrect file format"
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop While Not blnFileFound

    'Now open the Excel spreadsheet chosen in the previous section
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FName)
    objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

    'If a client has requested multiple Items, the third party's Excel dump will merge the client's info
    '    across multiple rows (one for each Item)
    'What we're going to do is find the merged cells and un-merge them, then concatenate the requests

    'Next, find the column containing the Item requested, usually around column 26
    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim rngItem As Excel.Range  'there's a significant difference between Word.Range and Excel.Range!!
    Dim rngHeader As Excel.Range
    Dim intItemCol As Integer
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strTemp As String

    Set sh = objWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    strSearch = "Service / Subsidy"

    'find the Item  column
    Set rngHeader = sh.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows

    Set rngItem = rngHeader.Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rngItem Is Nothing Then
        rngItem.Cells(1).Select
        intItemCol = rngItem.Column
    Else
        MsgBox "Can't find the Item column, please ensure you selected the correct spreadsheet!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Next, run through the rows, and if a client has multiple Items, concatenate them
    ' Also, add up the costs (the next column from the Items)
    ' and delete anything to the right of the costs
    Dim intCurrentRow As Integer
    Dim intRowsInMerge As Integer
    Dim strItems As String
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim intCost As Integer

    intCurrentRow = 2
    'find merged rows, concatenate services, add up costs, then delete the now-duplicate items (and other cells to the right) from the row
    'if the current row is merged, concatenate the merged rows' Item choices and costs
    While Not IsEmpty(sh.Cells(intCurrentRow, 1))

        If sh.Cells(intCurrentRow, 1).MergeCells Then
            'we've hit the first row of a multi-row entry
            strItems = ""
            intCost = 0
            intRowsInMerge = sh.Cells(intCurrentRow, 1).MergeArea.Rows.Count    'how many rows in this merge area?

            'for each row in the merged area, extract the Item and concatenate with the ones that have gone before
            For intIndex = intCurrentRow To intCurrentRow + intRowsInMerge - 1
                strTemp = sh.Cells(intIndex, intItemCol).Value
                intCost = intCost + CInt(sh.Cells(intIndex, intItemCol + 1).Value)

                'remove the trailing slash, artifact from the spreadsheet creation
                strTemp = Left(strTemp, InStrRev(strTemp, "/") - 1)

                If strItems = "" Then
                    strItems = strTemp
                Else
                    strItems = strItems & vbCrLf & strTemp
                End If

                ' remove the item from any line that isn't the first in the merged area
                ' this isn't the cleanest way, but it was expedient
                If intIndex > intCurrentRow Then
                    sh.Cells(intIndex, intItemCol).Value = ""
                    sh.Cells(intIndex, intItemCol + 1).Value = ""
                    sh.Cells(intIndex, intItemCol + 2).Value = ""
                    sh.Cells(intIndex, intItemCol + 3).Value = ""
                    sh.Cells(intIndex, intItemCol + 4).Value = ""
                End If
            Next intIndex

            sh.Cells(intCurrentRow, intItemCol).Value = strItems

            intCurrentRow = intCurrentRow + intRowsInMerge

        Else    'not a merged row, just a single item for this client; just remove the trailing /
            strItems = sh.Cells(intCurrentRow, intItemCol).Value
            strItems = Left(strItems, InStrRev(strItems, "/") - 1)
            sh.Cells(intCurrentRow, intItemCol).Value = strItems
            intCurrentRow = intCurrentRow + 1
        End If

        DoEvents
    Wend 'end searching for merged cells

    'now un-merge all rows (but don't "copy-down"... we want them to be blank)
    Dim Cell As Excel.Range
    For Each Cell In sh.UsedRange
        If Cell.MergeCells Then
            Cell.MergeCells = False
        End If
    Next

    'now remove any blank rows -- starting at the bottom!
    Dim rngUsed As Excel.Range
    Dim intLastRowIndex As Integer
    Dim intRowIndex As Integer

    ' find the last (effective) row
    If objExcel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells) <> 0 Then
        intLastRowIndex = _
            sh.Cells.Find( _
                What:="*", _
                After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        intLastRowIndex = 1
    End If

    'now delete any rows where the first cell is empty
    For intRowIndex = intLastRowIndex To 1 Step -1
        If sh.Cells(intRowIndex, 1) = "" Then
            sh.Rows(intRowIndex).Delete
        End If
    Next intRowIndex

    'save the new workbook with temporary name
    Dim strTempWorkbookName As String
    strTempWorkbookName = objWorkbook.Path & "\tempOutput_" & RandomString(10) & ".xlsx"
    objWorkbook.SaveAs strTempWorkbookName
    objWorkbook.Close

    'now mail merge the forms
    Dim wdocSource As Word.Document
    Dim wdocDest As Word.Document
    Dim myMerge As Word.MailMerge

    Set wdocSource = Application.ActiveDocument
    'Set wdocDest = Application.Documents.Add
    Set myMerge = wdocSource.MailMerge

    myMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

    myMerge.OpenDataSource _
            Name:=strTempWorkbookName, _
            Connection:="Data Source=" & strTempWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `CustomReport$`"

    With myMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = intLastRowIndex
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

    'release and close object and file handles
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    Set sh = Nothing
    Set wdocSource = Nothing
    Set wdocDest = Nothing

End Sub  ' end Document_open()

Function RandomString(Length As Integer)
    dim str as String
    str = "randomString" 'develop a random string function here
  RandomString = str

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you to all who responded and gave me hints. I appreciate your time and only hope I can return the favor to others!

Answer (score 1):

A mailmerge will not do what you want with vertically-merged cells in the data source. You need to have either:

• all the data for each name on a single row, in which case the merge is quite straightforward; or

• the name on every row, in which case the merge can be done as a directory merge or, if you also have a separate sheet with just the names, a normal merge employing a DATABASE field.

Comment: I concur... I think my next attempt will be to programatically de-merge the cells, then concatenate the selection cells into the row with the user's data.